# jquery uniform pixelmatrixdesign

Tags: jquery, uniform

I have a problem with slow computers/browsers, before rendering the styled uniform dropdowns, the users see the "normal" drops, and then it changes to the applied style.

I can´t find a callback function where i could show a div after the style is applied

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed your code in

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    //Code here
})
```

Comment: Yes i did, it only happens in slow machines, because while de document gets ready, people see the drops with no style

Comment: Solved
I just put style="display:none;" in my drops and the uniform plugin did the rest, thanks